# PHP: Calling a method on a class property that is an object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can anyone let me know if this is good practice or if there is a better cleaner way to do it? It looks very clumsy to me, so I'm wondering if there's a reason I haven't seen it before.

```
Class A {
  public $instance_of_b;

  function __construct () {
    $this->instance_of_b = new B;
  }

  function deeper_hello() {
    $this->instance_of_b->say_hi();
  }
}

Class B {
  public function say_hi() {
    echo "Hello, from B!";
  } 
}

$instance_of_a = new A;
$instance_of_a->deeper_hello();
```

It parses as PHP so it's not semanticly wrong, but is there a cleaner way of doing it?

I should say, this is CLEARLY not actually my code, it's just the method. What I'm actually doing is creating an SQL class that uses PDO. In that SQL class, I'm recording the PDO and the PDOStatment objects in the properties of the SQL class.

Comment: As the `$instance_of_b` property is public, `$instance_of_a->instance_of_b->say_hi();` will also work

Comment: But there's nothing wrong with that practise, it's quite common

Answer (score 0):

Rather than instantiating B inside of A, it would be better to pass B to A via the constructor. This is called dependency injection and by doing this A is no longer tightly coupled to B.

```
Class A {
  public $instance_of_b;

  function __construct ($b) {
    $this->instance_of_b = $b;
  }

  function deeper_hello() {
    $this->instance_of_b->say_hi();
  }
}

Class B {
  public function say_hi() {
    echo "Hello, from B!";
  } 
}

$instance_of_b = new B;
$instance_of_a = new A($instance_of_b);
$instance_of_a->deeper_hello();
```